# Unable to compile drools-examples-android project in droolsjbpm-integration repo

Tags: android, maven, drools

I am trying to compile the `drools-examples-android` project in `droolsjbpm-integration` repo, but with no success until now.

I have installed the dependencies as was mentioned in the `install-dependencies.sh`, but when I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` I get the following error:

```
    D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android>mvn clean install -DskipTests
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] The following dependencies may conflict with the internal versions provided by the Android platform:
    [org.khronos:opengl-api:jar:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1:provided, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:provided, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:provided, xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:provided, org.json:json:jar:20090211:provided]
    It is recommended to shade these artifacts. You can read more about this here: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/shaded-commons-codec.html.
    Alternatively, you can disable this warning with the'disableConflictingDependenciesWarning' parameter.
    [WARNING] The following dependencies may conflict with the internal versions provided by the Android platform:
    [org.khronos:opengl-api:jar:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1:provided, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:provided, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:provided, xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:provided, org.json:json:jar:20090211:provided]
    It is recommended to shade these artifacts. You can read more about this here: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/shaded-commons-codec.html.
    Alternatively, you can disable this warning with the'disableConflictingDependenciesWarning' parameter.
    [WARNING] The following dependencies may conflict with the internal versions provided by the Android platform:
    [org.khronos:opengl-api:jar:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1:provided, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:provided, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:provided, xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:provided, org.json:json:jar:20090211:provided]
    It is recommended to shade these artifacts. You can read more about this here: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/shaded-commons-codec.html.
    Alternatively, you can disable this warning with the'disableConflictingDependenciesWarning' parameter.
    [WARNING] The following dependencies may conflict with the internal versions provided by the Android platform:
    [org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:provided, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided, org.khronos:opengl-api:jar:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1:provided, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:provided, xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:provided, org.json:json:jar:20090211:provided]
    It is recommended to shade these artifacts. You can read more about this here: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/shaded-commons-codec.html.
    Alternatively, you can disable this warning with the'disableConflictingDependenciesWarning' parameter.
    [WARNING] The following dependencies may conflict with the internal versions provided by the Android platform:
    [org.khronos:opengl-api:jar:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1:provided, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:provided, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:provided, xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:provided, org.json:json:jar:20090211:provided]
    It is recommended to shade these artifacts. You can read more about this here: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/shaded-commons-codec.html.
    Alternatively, you can disable this warning with the'disableConflictingDependenciesWarning' parameter.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Drools Android examples
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Serialized KnowledgeBase
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - KieContainer
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Roboguice Serialized KnowledgeBase
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Roboguice KieContainer
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Roboguice KieContainer - Instrumentation Test
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Drools Android examples 6.4.0.Final
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Deleting D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\target
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-plugin-versions) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (ban-uberjars) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (validate) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (no-managed-deps) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (get-scm-revision) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify HEAD"
    [INFO] Working directory: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android
    [INFO] Storing buildNumber: c43ed9cdb6a4d2a4c6df4b8533d6c8a79cc250b7 at timestamp: 1494877433234
    [WARNING] Cannot get the branch information from the git repository:
    Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

    [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify HEAD"
    [INFO] Working directory: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android
    [INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source (default) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Source directory: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\target\generated-sources\annotations added.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:parse-version (default) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:4.2.1:manifest-update (manifest) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-direct-dependencies) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Flag 'useClassesFromLastBuild' is set. Try to use existing output folder.
    [INFO] Analyze dependencies of artifact 'org.drools:drools-examples-android:pom:6.4.0.Final'.
    [INFO] Nothing to analyze in 'org.drools:drools-examples-android:pom:6.4.0.Final'.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:test-jar (test-jar) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
    [INFO] Building jar: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\target\drools-examples-android-6.4.0.Final-tests.jar
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.4:test-jar-no-fork (attach-test-sources) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test (default) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ drools-examples-android ---
    [INFO] Installing D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\pom.xml to C:\Users\adasgupta\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-examples-android\6.4.0.Final\drools-examples-android-6.4.0.Final.pom
    [INFO] Installing D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\target\drools-examples-android-6.4.0.Final-tests.jar to C:\Users\adasgupta\.m2\repository\org\drools\drools-examples-android\6.4.0.Final\drools-examples-android-6.4.0.Final-tests.jar
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Drools Android examples - Serialized KnowledgeBase 6.4.0.Final
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Deleting D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-plugin-versions) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (ban-uberjars) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (validate) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (no-managed-deps) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (get-scm-revision) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:4.2.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Manifest copied from D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml to D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\AndroidManifest.xml
    [INFO] Extracting libs
    [INFO] Generating R file for org.drools:serialized-kbase:apk:6.4.0.Final
    [INFO] Adding R gen folder to compile classpath: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\generated-sources\r
    [INFO] Adding AIDL gen folder to compile classpath: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\generated-sources\aidl
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source (default) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Source directory: D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\generated-sources\annotations added.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:parse-version (default) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- kie-maven-plugin:6.4.0.Final:touch (touch) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Touching KBase: HelloKB
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 2 resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:4.2.1:manifest-update (manifest) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Attempting to update manifest D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\AndroidManifest.xml
    [INFO] Setting android:versionName to 6.4.0.Final
    [INFO] Setting android:versionCode to 6004000
    [INFO] Testing if node application is application
    [INFO] Setting android:debuggable to true
    [INFO] Made changes to manifest file, updating D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\AndroidManifest.xml
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\target\classes
    [WARNING] ootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\src\main\java\org\drools\examples\android\DroolsActivity.java:[40,23] [deprecation] KnowledgeBase in org.kie.internal has been deprecated
    [WARNING] D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\src\main\java\org\drools\examples\android\DroolsActivity.java:[106,22] [deprecation] KnowledgeBase in org.kie.internal has been deprecated
    [WARNING] D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\src\main\java\org\drools\examples\android\DroolsActivity.java:[107,94] [unchecked] unchecked cast
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- kie-maven-plugin:6.4.0.Final:build (compile-kbase) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] Adding KieModule from resource: FileResource[file=D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\src\main\resources]
    [WARNING] Unable to find pom.properties in /D:/temp/drools/droolsjbpm-integration/drools-examples-android/serialized-kbase/src/main/resources
    [INFO] Recursed up folders, found and used pom.xml D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\pom.xml
    [INFO] KieModule was added: FileKieModule[releaseId=org.drools:serialized-kbase:6.4.0.Final,file=D:\temp\drools\droolsjbpm-integration\drools-examples-android\serialized-kbase\src\main\resources]
    [INFO] KieModule successfully built!
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- kie-maven-plugin:6.4.0.Final:serialize (serialize) @ serialized-kbase ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Drools Android examples ............................ SUCCESS [  4.337 s]
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Serialized KnowledgeBase . FAILURE [  7.223 s]
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - KieContainer ............. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Roboguice Serialized KnowledgeBase SKIPPED
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Roboguice KieContainer ... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Drools Android examples - Roboguice KieContainer - Instrumentation Test SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 16.676 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-16T01:14:02+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 83M/335M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.4.0.Final:serialize (serialize) on project serialized-kbase: Unable to retrieve component configurator include-project-dependencies for configuration of mojo org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.4.0.Final:serialize: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    [ERROR] role: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurator
    [ERROR] roleHint: include-project-dependencies
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command`enter code here`
    [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :serialized-kbase
```